# mail- sending Output as attachment and not in the body

Tags: php, bash, email, cron

Am having a issue when trying to output the content of a PHP Script to email.
Every time i try, regardless of the method, the Output always ends up as an attachment. 
I was thinking it may of something to do with HTML. 
But when passing the -html via Mail i still am faced with the same problem.

Some of the things i have attempted:

```
Cron254=$(php httpdocs/DIR/Cron-Run.php) | echo $Cron254 | mail -s "cron output" email@domain.com <<< $Cron254
```

This gives me an attachment with the following content in the file:

```
 <b> 00 Days, 00 Hours, 37 Minutes, and 11 Seconds have passed since the session was started </b>
 <br/> 
 This script will auto end in 3 hours (180 minutes) its possible the time may need extending the more data that is on the website <br />
 Todays Timestamp: 20160229142124
 <br />
 Todays Timestamp -180 minutes: 20160229112124
 <br />
 session already in progress
 <br />
```

I also tried the simple method:

```
php /dir/to/script.php > output | mail -s "cron output" email@domain.com
```

I can find 1000 ways to do this, but every way appears to attach the file to the email.

Comment: Why don't you just simply compose email with phpmailer?

Comment: This is adding a extra load to the PHP Script that i dont want. 
I actually have a massive list of Cron jobs using this same function throughout. But for some reason THIS one does not like the output and wants to attach it.
Example: 
    data=$(grep 'STRING' logs/error_log) ; [[ -n "$data" ]] && mail -s 'Your Have Errors This Morning' youremail@domain.com <<< "$data"

Comment: I have also tried:  sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g' and also Strings passing the Variable across to clean up invalid char

Comment: Your first method is very byzantine. Your "simple" method is getting closer, but you're sending all the PHP output to a file instead of to mail. Try this: `php httpdocs/DIR/Cron-Run.php | mail -s "cron output" email@domain.com`